# How to add availability to receive another tokens as a payment

Tags: solidity, bsc, binance, payments

I created some kind of nft marketplace, deployed to BSC. So gonna use BNB as a main payment.
Please advise how to solve the following questions:

1. How to add additional ERC20 token as a payment that is already deployed on BSC?
   Is it possible to use some bridge or wrap for this additional token?
2. How to add ETH, wBTC for payments and also minting nft's?

Comment: I'm sorry for my irrelevant reply to your question but would it be possible for you to help me create something similar ?(just a newbie getting started on nft development)

Comment: You could use an exchange like pancake swap to automatically swap any token to BNB.